# Mount thermal imaging camera on ordinary optical microscope?

Tags: thermal-radiation

Anyone tried mounting thermal imaging camera on ordinary optical microscope?

I know it is unlikely to work. Because of different refraction index and possible absorption of IR radiation by the lens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The glass used in visible light microscopes does not pass much IR. For strong signals you need calcium fluorite lenses, which are expensive and rare.